# Why does conceptual storage allocation differ from the actual?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, static-memory-allocation

### I have a puzzling question (at least for me)

Say I declare an integer array:

```
int arr[3];
```

Conceptually, what happens in the memory is that, at compile time, 12 bytes are allocated to store 3 consecutive integers, right? ([Here's an illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZSZP.png))

Based on the illustration, the sample addresses of

`arr[0]` is `1000`,

`arr[1]` is `1004`, and

`arr[2]` is `1008`.

---

**My question is:**

If I output the difference between the addresses of `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`:

```
std::cout << &arr[1] - &arr[0] << std::endl;
```

instead of getting `4`,

I surprisingly get `1`.

Can anybody explain why it resulted to that output?

*PS: On my computer, an int is 4 bytes.*

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic, you'll receive the number of elements not bytes.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite get it. Dealing with addresses (like adding, subtracting, multiplying, diviing)  is dealing with bytes, no?

Comment: _@Christian_ No. Note these are typed addresses, not like `void*`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I get it now :D thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic automatically divides the value by the size of the base type so this is not surprising at all since one would expect to get `4 / 4` which is `1`. Cast to `unsignd char *` to see the difference.

```
#include <iostream>

int
main(void)
{
    int arr[2];

    std::cout << &arr[1] - &arr[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&arr[1]) -
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&arr[0]) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```